# JSON SharePoint list view - background-image doest not work

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting, view-formatting

I found in documentation that "background-image" is supported attribute but I am not able to use it. Maybe I am doing something wrong. Could you help please, how to use "background-image" within JSON code?

Example:

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
        "text-align": "left",
        "background-image": "url('https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/TEST/SiteAssets/company_logo.png')"
    }
...
```

Thank you,

Mirek

Comment: Where are you trying this? in view formatting or column formatting? Refer [this](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1161)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

Currently style properties cannot have any of the following characters: `(`, `:`, `&`, `;`, `!`.

If you will add `"debugMode": "true"` to your JSON code, you can see the error message like below in browser's console:

[image]

You can read more information about this issue at: [Column formatting - URL not allowed in background-image style property](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1161)

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! :) Then I do not just understand why it is as a supported attribute (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#style). Quite confusing.

Comment: Yes, I checked that. Not sure why it is there. But, it should have been removed as mentioned by repo maintainer [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1161#issuecomment-579035257).